# Java/JPA class for storing application settings

Tags: java, jpa, servlets

How can I use JPA to create a `Settings` class for my Java Servlet application? I'm thinking of something like a static class with a map of key/value pairs for storing the application settings like e-mail server address etc. Something like this:

```
public class ApplicationSettings {

    private static Map<String, String> settings;
```

Comment: why can't you use properties or yml configurations

Comment: @NidhishKrishnan I'd like to persist the settings to the database so that they are preserved across application updates.

Comment: Ok then you can store the properties in the database and you can load those into cache when the application starts up ....so that every-time you don't need to load the properties from database (I hope so the properties will always remain constant)

Comment: No the settings are  not constant. They can be configured by the application's admin user.

Comment: Will these configuration be changed frequently

Comment: No not frequently, typically they will be set once after the application installation. But they may be changed infrequently after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## For Spring based application

You can use Caching for storing the properties from database. You can use `@Cacheable("properties")` for calling the database service and load it in the cache. If you want to update, delete or add new property you can use `@CacheEvict(value = "properties", allEntries = true)` where you can call the database service to use do the actual operation. `@CacheEvict` will clear all the existing cache mapped for `properties` key and loads the new properties by calling `@Cacheable("properties")` implicitly

```
@Repository
public class ApplicationSettings {

    private DatabaseService databaseService;

    public ApplicationSettings(DatabaseService databaseService) {
        this.databaseService = databaseService;
    }

    @Cacheable("properties")
    public Map<String, String> getAppProperties() {
        return databaseService.getAppProperties();
    }

    @CacheEvict(value = "properties", allEntries = true)
    public void updateAppProperties(String key, String value) throws IOException {
        databaseService.updateAppProperties(key, value);
    }
}
```

You can now use `ApplicationSettings` wherever want can the properties like

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationSettings applicationSettings;

:
:
Map<String, String> appProperties = applicationSettings.getAppProperties();
```

## For Servlet based application

You can use EhCache or simply use Sevlet Listener for achieving the above scenario

in web.xml

```
<web-app ....>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
    com.listernerpackage.ApplicationInitializationListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
:
```

Create a ServletContextListener

```
public class ApplicationInitializationListener implements ServletContextListener {    
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        ServletContext context = event.getServletContext();
        Map<String, String> properties = someDbManager.getAppProperties(); 
        context.setAttribute("properties", properties );           
    }
}
```

You can retrieve the properties in servlet by calling

```
Map<String, String> properties = (Map<String, String>) this.getContext().getAttribute("properties");
```

Comment: Thanks Nidhish, will be looking into this. I guess the BookRepository comes from somewhere else.

Comment: Nidish, it seems that your answer assumes that the Spring framework is used. My application does not use Spring. It's pure Java Servlets with JPA.

Comment: @geschema You can use ehcache or ServletContextListener .... I have updated with one example